# Let $S$ be an ordered set. Let $A$ subset of $B$ be a nonempty subset that is bounded above.

Tags: real-analysis

Let $S$ be an ordered set. Let $A \subset S$ be a nonempty subset that is bounded above. Suppose $\sup A$ exists and $\sup A$ is not in $A$. Show that $A$ contains a countably infinite subset. In particular, $A$ is infinite.

Let $x_0 ∈ A $

then $x_0$ is not equal to $\sup(A)$ since $x_0 ∈ A$

Then, by definition of $\sup (A)$, there has got to be another element $x_1 ∈ A$ such that $x_1 > x_0 $

I don't understand why there has got to be another element $x_1$

I know the definition of $ \sup (A)$.

$\sup (A)$ is greater than or equal to all elements of $A$.

But in problem $\sup A$ is not in $A$. From that I can conclude $x_0 < \sup A$

**My question is:** Why there has to be another element?

Comment: Because otherwise $x_0$ would be an upper bound smaller than the supremum.

Comment: I don't understand why.. $x_0$ would be an upper bound......?

Comment: If there isn't an element $x_1 > x_0$ it means that $x_0$ is an upper bound.

Comment: These are sets of real numbers or they are just sets?

Comment: but how $x_0$ be upper bound when it is in A ? is there any rules about that...?

Comment: I think they are set of real number. This section is about real numbers.

Comment: Here lets give some examples where the set has an upper bound. Let $A: \{x\in \mathbb Q | 0 \leq x \leq 1\}$. In this example 1 is the $\sup$ of $A$, and is contained in $A$. Now lets look at $B:\{x\in \mathbb Q | 0 \leq x < 1\}$. Now this is a situation that 1 is clearly the $\sup$ of $B$ and $1\notin B$. Notice how if you chose a rational number say $x_n <1$ that is ridiculously close to 1, I can still chose another rational number say $x_{n+1}$ such that $x_n < x_{n+1} <1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $x_0 \in A \subset S$. Suppose that there does not exist another $x_1 \in A$ such that $x_1 > x_0$. This implies that $x_0$ is an upper bound of $A$

$$\forall x \in A \implies x < x_0$$

Because $S$ is ordered we have that $A$ is ordered and then we can have the above implication. Now this is the least upper bound possible. If there is another upper bound, say $u$, we must have $u \geq x_0$ because if it is such that $u < x_0$ then, by definition, $u$ is **not** an upper bound, because $x_0 \in A$. **The upper bound must be greater (or equal) than all numbers of the set**. So, with this, we get that $x_0$ is the supremum.

But this is not possible because the supremum cannot be an element of $A$ so there must exist $x_1$. Because $x_0$ was arbitrary we must have that $A$ is infinite.

Note that you use two absurd arguments: If does not exist and element grater I get an upper bound, using absurd argument this must be supremum, using absurd argument this is impossible. Tried to make it clear. Comment for EDIT's such that you can understand.

Comment: so if A has only one element ${x_0}$, it satisfies the definition of upper bound, which is that "The upper bound must be greater (or equal) than all numbers of the set". so  There should be $x_0 < x_1 $ ? because it doesnt satisfies "every element" from upper bound definition.

Comment: I meam $x_0 $cannot be upper bound

Comment: Yes. That's precisely what he means and why there must be an element $x_1\geq x_0$ in $A$. Also $x_0$ can't be an upper bound otherwise $x_0\geq \sup A$ and thus $x_0\notin A$

Answer (score 1):

Otherwise $\forall x \in A$, $x \leq x_0$, then $x_0$ is upper bound of $A$, let $y$ another upper bound of $A$, then $y \geq x_0$  then $x_0$ is the smaller upper bound, therefore $x_0 = sup(A)$.

Comment: Could you explain why if $A = { x_0 }$, then $x_0$ is uppper bound of A .. ?

Comment: Because in this case $x_0 \geq x$ $ \forall x$ $ \in A$.

Comment: I finally got it. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Importantly, $\sup{A}$ is the *least* upper bound on $A$. If there isn't a member of $A$ larger than $x_0$, then $x_0$ is itself an upper bound on $A$ - that's just what "upper bound" means. Since $\sup{A}$ is the *least* upper bound, it must be that $\sup{A} \leq x_0$. But $\sup{A}$ is certainly an upper bound, so $x_0 \leq \sup{A}$. So we would have $x_0 = \sup{A}$, and since $x_0 \in A$ we would have $\sup{A} \in A$. Since that can't be the case, it must be that there *is* a member of $A$ larger than $x_0$.